# std classes interpreted as singletons by Doxygen 1.8.8

Tags: singleton, doxygen

In our system, we have a namespace ABC, which refers to std classes such as List, Deque etc

I generate a .tag file in the library TestLib, which uses some of these classes.

When I generated that .tag file with 1.8.7, I saw the following in the .tag file:

```
    <compound kind="class">
            <name>ABC::Deque</name>
            <filename>classABC_1_1Deque.html</filename>
            <templarg></templarg>
            <member kind="function">
                    <type></type>
                    <name>Deque</name>
                    <anchorfile>classABC_1_1Deque.html</anchorfile>
                    <anchor>fghjfghjfghjygjfghjfghj</anchor>
                    <arglist>()</arglist>
            </member>
    </compound>
```

However, using the same sources, I generated the .tag file using 1.8.8 and now the line is as follows:

```
    <compound kind="singleton">
            <name>ABC::Deque</name>
            <filename>classABC_1_1Deque.html</filename>  
            <templarg></templarg>
            <member kind="function">
                    <type></type>
                    <name>Deque</name>
                    <anchorfile>classABC_1_1Deque.html</anchorfile>
                    <anchor>fghjfghjfghjygjfghjfghj</anchor>
                    <arglist>()</arglist>
            </member>
    </compound>
```

I don't know what made the compound kind change to a "singleton".

Various other libraries access the TestLib.tag file in the TestLib library. 
However, when they do so, warning messages appear, as follows: 
~/doc/library/TestLib/TestLib.tag:1655: warning: Unknown compound attribute `singleton' found! 
~/doc/library/TestLib/TestLib.tag:1656: warning: Unexpected tag`name' found 
~/doc/library/TestLib/TestLib.tag:1657: warning: Unexpected tag `filename' found 
~/doc/library/TestLib/TestLib.tag:1658: warning: Unexpected tag`templarg' found 
~/doc/library/TestLib/TestLib.tag:1705: warning: Unexpected tag `member' found 
~/doc/library/TestLib/TestLib.tag:1706: warning: tag`compound' was not expected!

Why is the class Deque being called a singleton in 1.8.8, but was not in 1.8.7? 
Also, why are there warning messages for the singleton in 1.8.8 ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug, see also
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=735376

It has been fixed in GitHub in the meantime by this commit
https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/commit/92eb236037e857f38eaf24238815641a48540792